# Why doesn't my mysql query in php return more than one row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am trying to return a list of users' first and last names in JSON format in PHP.

My PHP looks something like:

```
    $_Query = '
                    SELECT
                    Fname,Lname
                    FROM
                    users
                    WHERE
                    number = "'.$_REQUEST['number'].'"
                                                    ;';

    $SQLResult = mysql_query($_Query) or die(mysql_error());

    $_UserData = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($SQLResult) <> 0){

            while($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_array($SQLResult)){
                    $_UserData['Fname'] = $SQLRow['Fname'];
                    $_UserData['Lname'] = $SQLRow['Lname'];
            }

    }
echo json_encode($_UserData);
```

I expect more than one row in the format

```
{"Fname":["First_name1","First_name2"],"Lname":["Last_name1","Last_name2"]}
```

of course. However the script returns the last row with the correct conditions

```
{"Fname":"Steve","Lname":"LastName"}
```

The MySQl server returns what it should with the same query.

```
+--------------+-------------+
| Fname        | Lname       |
+--------------+-------------+
| First_name1  | Last_name1  |
| First_name2  | Last_name2  |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Why is this happening and how should I go about fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: Because your loop overwrites the previous values, so you always, and only, get the last record.

Comment: `mysql_query` is vulnerable to SQL injections attacks. Do not use it in production code (and generally there is no reason to use it). Use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: @Andy @Alex thanks for that, I'll take a look. Though, why doesn't `htmlspecialchars()` take care of that?

Comment: `htmlspecialcharacters` has absolutely nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_array($SQLResult)){
    $_UserData[] = $SQLRow;
}
```

In your example you are essentially overwriting the $_UserData array for every new row, hence the missing rows.

**UPDATE**:
This will make the JSON string look more the way you want it.

```
while($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQLResult)){
    $_UserData['Fname'][] = $SQLRow['Fname'];
    $_UserData['Lname'][] = $SQLRow['Lname'];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, which @Sagi also suggested and I get
`[{"0":"First_name1","Fname":"First_name1","1":"Last_name1","Lname":"Last_name1"},{"0":"First_name2","Fname":"First_name2","1":"Last_name2","Lname":"Last_name2"}]`

Comment: You can use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array(): while ($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQLResult)) { ... This should get rid of the numbered entries in the json string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_UserData['Fname'] = $SQLRow['Fname'];
$_UserData['Lname'] = $SQLRow['Lname'];
```

You're repeatedly setting the same two elements of _UserData, rather than appending new values to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop overrides the values in $_UserData array.
You should **append** each row to the array.

In addition, please note that you should escape your input.

Your code should look like this:

```
$_Query = '
                SELECT
                Fname,Lname
                FROM
                users
                WHERE
                number = "'.(int)$_REQUEST['number'].'"
                                                ;';

$SQLResult = mysql_query($_Query) or die(mysql_error());

$_UserData = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($SQLResult) <> 0){

        while($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_array($SQLResult)){
                $_UserData[] = $SQLRow;
        }

}
echo json_encode($_UserData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

$_UserData = array();

```
if(mysql_num_rows($SQLResult) <> 0){
        $i = 0;
        while($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_array($SQLResult)){
                $_UserData[$i]['Fname'] = $SQLRow['Fname'];
                $_UserData[$i]['Lname'] = $SQLRow['Lname'];
                $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll kick yourself when you realise that you've only assigned to 1 element of your $_UserData array.

Should be something like:

```
$_UserData = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($SQLResult) <> 0){

        while($SQLRow = mysql_fetch_array($SQLResult)){
                // Either...
                // Create a new entry in $_UserData with same structure and contents as $SQLRow
                $_UserData[] = $SQLRow;
                // OR more specific - say if the structures aren't identical
                // $DataRow=array();
                // $DataRow['Fname'] = $SQLRow['Fname'];
                // $DataRow['Lname'] = $SQLRow['Lname'];
                // $_UserData[] = $DataRow;
        }

}
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried the second way (DataRow=array() ) and it worked, however, is there a way to return all first names and last names in arrays so 
    `{"Fname:["F-name1","F-name2"],...`
etc. ?